# GNU inetutils pre-compilation problems

Tags: debian, compile, gnu

I am trying to compile GNU inteutils on Debian and experiencing some problems. configure is going thru without any issues but when I launch make to compile I receive the following messages:

> lib/Makefile.am:1731: GL_GENERATE_STDALIGN_H does not appear in
>   AM_CONDITIONAL man/Makefile.am:98: ENABLE_telnet does not appear in
>   AM_CONDITIONAL tests/Makefile.am:57: ENABLE_hostname does not appear
>   in AM_CONDITIONAL ... ...

I haven't done any modifications to any of the files except launching configure with --prefix=/path/

please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after small research I found inetutils 1.9 archive contained incomplete config files.

obtaining inetutils 1.9.1 sources compilation worked as a charm

here is a link to the sources http://fossies.org/unix/misc/inetutils-1.9.1.tar.gz/